# timeout command is not working with python along with Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Can some please guide, why command is not timing out. Below is my Python code

```
python
>>>from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>>command="timeout 5 su - user -c \"user admin display_states\""
>>>print command
timeout 5 su - user "user admin display_states"
>>>process=Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=TRUE)
>>>(output,error)=process.communicate()
(Doesn't terminate after 5 seconds)
```

Execution on cmd prompt:

```
Linux>timeout 5 su - user -c "user admin display_states"
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
```

I expect the timeout command to terminate after 5 seconds, which is not happening in my Python code.

Comment: What if you just cat something smaller or sleep for six seconds? I guess your interpretation is flawed and that it's the amount of output and the according buffer overruns that cause the issue. IOW, it's blocked on IO instead.

Comment: I have corrected the code with the correct error message for more guidance

Comment: Are you stuck on Python 2? Are you unable to switch to Python 3?

Comment: i m on python 2

Answer (score 0):

Python has no control over the `timeout` command. Presumably the subprocess has already buffered much more output than you have been able to consume when it times out, and so it looks like it's still running, even though it's really not.

The workaround is simple in this case, though; use a timeout from Python instead.

```
process = subprocess.run(["su", "-", "user", "-c", "user admin display_states"], timeout=5, text=True, capture_output=True)
# output, error = process.stdout, process.stderr
```

You should generally prefer `subprocess.run` over bare `Popen` for the cases it can handle, though if you really need to, there is also a `timeout` parameter for the `communicate` method of `Popen`.

Tangentially, notice also how we avoid `shell=True` by passing the command as a list; you [generally want to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: `subprocess.run` is not available in Python 2; I don't think it supported any sort of timeout mechanism.